# Solving cubics with complex numbers, before complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers, math-history, cubics

An aside in another website reads:

> Complex numbers were used to solve cubic polynomials, before complex numbers were invented.

I tried Googling this technique but didn't get anywhere.

What is this person talking about?

Comment: That is not right: they were invented to make  the resolution formulae work in all cases. Of course they were not denoted the way they're denoted nowadays.

Comment: See the last paragraph of [this page](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~angenent/276/cubic.html) for example. A formula was found for solutions to cubic equations, that sometimes involved the square root of negative numbers, even when the cubic only had real roots. Cardano noticed this, and this was happening before anyone had seriously considered the square root of negative numbers.

Comment: Perhaps this question is a better fit for [hsm.se].

Comment: See also [this Q&A](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/34/26) over at [hsm.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 16th century, [Niccolo Tartaglia](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Tartaglia.html) created a method for solving special cases of cubic equations, namely, those of the form
$$x^3+ax^2=b$$
He later passed on the method to [Gerolamo Cardano](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Cardan.html) (who found out about them after a contest between Tartaglia and Antonio Fiore), on the condition that Cardano would never release the secret (which he eventually did, leading to an incredible public feud). Cardano found that, in certain cases, one must take the square of a negative number on order to use Tartaglia's method.

This appears to be what the quote is referring to.

It should be noted that the step involving a complex number was an intermediate one, and not of much importance to the final result. Additionally, Cardano eventually built off of the idea to solve cubics of the form
$$x^3+ax^2+bx=c$$